# Android Google map get shortest path distance between 5 locations from the current location?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I want find the **shortest path/route** between multiple locations available.
i.e. suppose I have five locations `A,B,C,D and E`, I want to find the nearest location **(using route distance not normal distance)**.

Currently I am making **5 URL** and calling `Google Direction API` for result and comparing them. But it's long and time consuming process. Is there any alternative?

I also thought of using `distanceTo()` and `distanceBetween()` method but i think it doesn't show the route distance.

Any suggestions please....
Thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968245/proximity-search-based-on-latitude-and-longitude/16413354#16413354), Haversine is what you require.

Comment: thanks for the reply ... i'll have a look..

Comment: Welcome, do check the .pdf document. Its all explained in there.

Comment: It's a great document but it's similar to `distanceTo` and `distanceBetween` method. It returns the direct distance between two location but i am looking for the route distance between these two locations...

Comment: Maybe KML is helpful in your case, I am not sure but you can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023669/j2me-android-blackberry-driving-directions-route-between-two-locations)

Comment: I have already found the route of two locations using Google Directions API (json format) but i want to calculate route distance for multiple locations at once. that's the issue i am having.

Comment: I am working on the same kind of project, I have to find shortest path between multiple locations.Please help me on this.Thanks in Advance.